# Show all options of dropdowlist using javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist control.

I want to using javascript to show all options of Mydropdowlist as event user click on dropdownlist.

I'm trying to use:

`$("#drpCountry").one("focus", function () {
                this.size = this.options.length;
            }).focus();`

but it not show as user click on dropdownlist(default show option).

Have any solution for me??

Here is the image when use dropdownlist.size:

[image]

Default show when click on dropdownlist:

[image]

Comment: What you mean? do you want show the all options on dropdown focus? or onclick?

Comment: I'm trying to use: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "scr", "ShowAllOption();", true); in code behide. when ShowAllOption method was call, all option of dropdownlist are showing.  And  ShowAllOption method is a javacript function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:30px;">
            <select id="AutoDropdown" OnMouseOver="DoDropDown(this);" OnMouseOut="DoDropDown(this);">

            </select>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function DoDropDown(objSel){

             if(objSel.size > 1){
              objSel.size = 1;
              objSel.style.position='static';
             }
             else{
              objSel.size = objSel.options.length;
              objSel.style.position='absolute';
              objSel.style.height='auto';
            }
        }

        </script>
```

This codes from @dash

See this discussion

[how to show all item of a dropdown list in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325342/how-to-show-all-item-of-a-dropdown-list-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
$("#drpCountry").click(function (){
            var size=($('#drpCountry option').size()); 
            $(this).attr("size",size);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks you, But I don't want to use dropdowlist.size, because it display as append HTML, I want it fadeout as when you click on dropdownlist.(I'm trying to learning English, If you don't understand, please tell me.:))

Comment: I've update a image when use dropdowlist.zise. I don't want display as image. :)

Comment: try this...  don't know is this exact what you are looking for `$("#drpCountry").click(function (){
   var size=($('#drpCountry option').size()); 
   $(this).attr("size",size);   
   $( this ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    $(this).attr("size","1"); 
    $(this).show();    
   });
  });`

Comment: :).Thanks for your support. But when we add size for a dropdownlist, it display not as default. Defaut show all options as when you click on dropdownlist. I want to create a method and it work as you click on dropdowlist. Thanks you again.:)